# css class selector parent > child

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is any add css rule to a parent class if is a child class is present? Like this

```
.parent{
some rules
}

.child{
some rules
}

.parent > .child{
add a rule to parent
}
```

I've this html

```
<div class="PARENT">
  <div class="something">
  <div class="something1"></div>
  <div class="CHILD"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope you can't with pure css.

Comment: You can change a style of a parent with some trick in javascript/jquery if you add a child.